# Maven Build Failure releated to com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins:s4sdk-maven-plugin

Tags: s4sdk

1. I am facing an issue during the Maven build. The issue on my
   terminal is: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
   com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins:s4sdk-maven-plugin:2.12.0:usage-analytics
   (default) on project demo-generator-application: Execution default
   of goal
   com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins:s4sdk-maven-plugin:2.12.0:usage-analytics
   failed: Plugin
   com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins:s4sdk-maven-plugin:2.12.0 or one of its
   dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies
   at com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins:s4sdk-maven-plugin:jar:2.12.0 ->
   com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins:usage-analytics:jar:2.12.1-M1: Failed
   to read artifact descriptor for
   com.sap.cloud.s4hana.plugins:usage-analytics:jar:2.12.1-M1: Failure
   to find com.sap.cloud.s4hana:sdk-modules-bom:pom:2.12.1-M1 in
   https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

The maven project I used can be found here:

- https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-examples/blob/master/VDMGenerator/application

The document can be found:

- https://blogs.sap.com/2018/04/30/deep-dive-10-with-sap-s4hana-cloud-sdk-generating-java-vdm-for-s4hana-custom-odata-service/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to run `mvn clean install -U` to force an update of dependencies.

Comment: Hi Sander, I tired that but it did not work. I think the problem is that the artifact can not be found in central maven repository. Do you have any idea where is the version number of "com.sap.cloud.s4hana:sdk-modules-bom" is defined?

Comment: Could you share your dependency tree via `mvn dependency:tree`?